# Compute absolute values of X and Y derivatives using OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

This seems like a pretty straightforward request, but I'm finding the problem a bit subtle. I just want 8-bit unsigned versions of X and Y derivatives. The source image is also 8-bit unsigned.

Here's one approach I've used:

```
  cv::Mat dx, dy;
  cv::Sobel(img, dx, CV_16S, 1, 0);
  cv::Sobel(img, dy, CV_16S, 0, 1);
  dx = cv::abs(dx);
  dy = cv::abs(dy);
  cv::normalize(dx, dx8u, 0x00, 0xFF, cv::NORM_MINMAX, CV_8U);
  cv::normalize(dy, dy8u, 0x00, 0xFF, cv::NORM_MINMAX, CV_8U);
```

What I don't really like is the use of the `normalize` function. It seems wasteful. If I try to compute the Sobel operator directly into an 8-bit image (by setting `ddepth` to `-1`), it appears to "cut off" all of the negative values. If I try to compute the absolute value and then divide by 8 (to approximately map the absolute value of Sobel operator to [0, 255]), it's still a 16-bit image and I need to convert it to 8-bit, which again seems wasteful. Is there a better way of doing this?

I suppose an important aspect of the question is how to perform operations on 16-bit signed images and somehow have the results placed directly into an 8-bit image. That way, you don't have to run an additional conversion after the fact.

**UPDATE:**

Here's the final solution:

```
  cv::Mat dx, dy;
  cv::Sobel(m, dx, CV_16S, 1, 0);
  cv::Sobel(m, dy, CV_16S, 0, 1);
  cv::convertScaleAbs(dx / 8, dx);
  cv::convertScaleAbs(dy / 8, dy);
```

Comment: Does your result need to be normalized to `[0, 255]`, or is it an artifact of attempting to get the absolute value?

Comment: @Aurelius Right -- there's no need for it to be exactly between [0,255], it's just one of the only methods I could find using OpenCV functions to get close to what I wanted. The normalize function converts the type to 8-bit as it operates, so it seemed fairly efficient in that regard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you simply need the absolute value of the gradient, without any normalization, you can use `cv::convertScaleAbs()`. This will find the absolute value and convert to 8-bit unsigned type in one go.

```
cv::Mat dx, dy;
cv::Sobel(img, dx, CV_16S, 1, 0);
cv::Sobel(img, dy, CV_16S, 0, 1);
cv::convertScaleAbs(dx, dx);
cv::convertScaleAbs(dy, dy);
```

Note that this method only calculates the absolute value of the derivative, and does not normalize the results to `[0, 255]`.

If you need a normalized result, then your posted code seems to be the best way to do it. As far as your method seeming "wasteful", make sure that making multiple data passes is a demonstrated performance bottleneck before worrying about "waste".

Unfortunately, OpenCV doesn't have much support for reducing the number of data passes. You could modify the source to do this, or implement the Sobel operation yourself if it is really necessary. But again, don't worry about it unless it's a proven problem.

Comment: Hmm, I like the use of this function. What happens to values greater than +/- 255? They're just clipped at that value?

Comment: Actually, in order to get what I want, I think I can just divide the original 16-bit values by 8, then call your function. I think this'll do the trick.

Comment: Yep, it works, thanks! Check out my question for my final answer.